# how to cross merge the rows from data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row

I have this column in dataframe:
`list = [dl, ab, ab, sh, dl, sh, dl, ab, sh]`

and I want to make it crossed like this:
`list = [dl, sh, ab, dl, sh, ab, dl, sh, ab]`
what is the fastest way to do it? I was thinking to group them by value then re-merge them. it's just about how to spread it evenly

Comment: Do you really have a dataframe? because your "df = [1,3,3,2,1,2,1,3,2]" is a list not a dataframe.

Comment: it's one of the columns from dataframe, yeah i think it might be just a list

Comment: I don't understand the logic of how you get from that list to your ouput. You say your actual output is names, could you add an example of the input/output with names (you can change/make up names if privacy is an issue)

Comment: it's muscles name so i don't want to sort it based on alphabet, just want to spread it equally